# calculating the height of a Minimum spannning tree

Tags: java

I need a JAVA code that could help me find the height of the Minimum spanning tree.
Basically i m looking for an extension of the 
Prim's/Kruskal's algo that not only gives the height of the MST but also gives its height.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But the output of Prim's algorithm is a tree. Can't you just calculate the height of the tree?

Comment: Furthermore there is "inherent" root by the constructed tree. So the "height" does not make any sense. You can have a randomized Prim's algorithm that each time produces different trees (with different heights).

Comment: This question is better suited for Computer Science (https://cs.stackexchange.com/) than StackOverflow. Consider moving the question there.

Answer (score 0):

Take as the root vertex one of the [tree's centers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) and calculate the maximal distance from the chosen center to the leaf nodes.

The height can the be calculated in the following way:

- set the height to 0
- while there are at least 3 remaining vertices:

  - delete all leaf vertices
  - height := height+1
- if 2 vertices remain:

  - height := height+1

the remaining vertices are the centers of the tree.
The time complexity is O(n).

A practical way of calculating the height would be to combine all leaf nodes int a single node that serves as a root, then calculate the MST of that modification and the height as the maximum distance from generated root node to the newly generated leaf nodes.

Answer (score -1):

I am not writing the code here, just giving you a hint. 
In every node keep a variable that stores the height/depth of that node.
So, depth for starting node will be 0. **Now, whenever you add a edge to the MST, increase the depth of the new node by 1**.

Currently you have the following discovered nodes with the following depth. 
**a  0**

**b 1**
**c 1**
Now suppose you want to add the edge from **c** to **d**, so the depth of node **d** will be **depth(c)+1**, i.e 1+1=2.


Also, you can keep a track of the maximum depth among all nodes at each step of the algorithm. 
So, finally answer will be the maximum depth among all the nodes of the tree.